# Use react-input-mask with antd in react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-final-form

I would like to use `react-input-mask` with Ant Design `Input` in `react-final-form`. In order to use `antd` with `react-final-form` I also had to install `redux-form-antd`. So the file looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Button } from "antd";
import { Form, Field } from "react-final-form";
import InputMask from "react-input-mask";
import { TextField } from "redux-form-antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

const onSubmit = async values => {
  window.alert(JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2));
};

const Input = props => <InputMask {...props} />;

function App() {
  return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      render={({ handleSubmit, values }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Field
            name="mask"
            parse={value =>
              value
                .replace(/\)/g, "")
                .replace(/\(/g, "")
                .replace(/-/g, "")
                .replace(/ /g, "")
            }
            render={({ input, meta }) => (
              <div>
                <label>mask phone</label>
                <Input mask="+7 (999) 999-99-99" {...input} />
                {meta.touched && meta.error && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
              </div>
            )}
          />
          <Field
            name="antd"
            component={TextField}
            label="antd phone"
            placeholder="Phone"
          />
          <Button className="submit-button" type="primary">
            Send
          </Button>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2)}</pre>
        </form>
      )}
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-input-mask-test-38js4?fontsize=14) example.

I could only get to work a regular `input` with an `InputMask` (input 1) or an `antd input` without a mask (input 2).

How can I add an `InputMask` to `antd input`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to use `react-input-mask` with `antd` and `react-final-form` without any external libraries.

Here is my component:

```
import React from "react";
import InputMask from "react-input-mask";
import { Input } from "antd";
import FormItem from "antd/lib/form/FormItem";

const MaskInput = props => {
  const { disabled, mask, label, meta, required } = props;
  return (
    <FormItem
      label={label}
      validateStatus={
        meta.touched ? (meta.error ? "error" : "success") : undefined
      }
      help={meta.touched ? (meta.error ? meta.error : undefined) : undefined}
      hasFeedback={meta.touched ? true : false}
      required={required}
    >
      <InputMask
        mask={mask}
        disabled={disabled}
        autoComplete="off"
        {...props.input}
      >
        <Input />
      </InputMask>
    </FormItem>
  );
};

export default MaskInput;
```

Then it is passed to the `component` prop of the `Field`:

```
<Field
  name="phone"
  label="Phone"
  component={MaskInput}
  mask="+7 (999) 999-99-99"
  required
/>
```

Here is the link to the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-formitem-as-component-wreact-input-mask-working-z39og?file=/src/index.js) example.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used either of those libraries, but you might want to check out using `format-string-by-pattern` with `react-final-form`'s built-in parsing and formatting functionality to achieve a similar thing.

I bet you could throw `redux-form-antd` components into here pretty easily...

[image: Edit format-string-by-pattern with react-final-form]

Comment: Erik, thank you very much for your reply. Although `format-string-by-pattern` could work for some simple masks, I can't get it to work with a mask for a phone number like this: `"+7 (999) 999-99-99"`. Is there any way to escape characters to make an unremovable prefix `+7 (`? Also is it possible to show mask on focus? And to change mask character to `"_"` instead of white space?

Comment: No idea... You'll have to contact that library author.

Comment: @jupiteror have you found a solution?

Comment: @BlueMark Unfortunately no, but we managed to do the same with `formik` and `formik-antd`. Checkout these two questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57191028/using-react-input-mask-with-formik-and-formik-antd/57192240#57192240 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57208048/using-setfieldvalue-onsubmit-in-formik

Comment: Seems like fixing the value in `onSubmit` could be done in RFF, too, no?