# Using react-input-mask with formik and formik-antd

Tags: reactjs, antd, formik

I'm using `formik` with `@jbuschke/formik-antd`. I need to apply a mask `+7 (___) ___-__-__` to an input, so I would like to use `react-input-mask`.

At the same time I need to parse the value and remove symbols except `+` and digits, so I handle `onChange` and `setFieldValue` myself. I can get `changedValue` in the console log, but on submit I'm getting the initial value, not the changed one.

Here is my code and the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-antd-wreact-input-mask-and-setfieldvalue-lpp5s?fontsize=14):

```
const CustomInput = props => (
  <InputMask {...props}>{inputProps => <Input {...inputProps} />}</InputMask>
);

const CloseForm = () => (
  <Formik
    initialValues={{ phone: "" }}
    onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        setSubmitting(false);
      }, 400);
    }}
    validate={handleValidate}
  >
    {({ isSubmitting, values, setFieldValue }) => {
      return (
        <Form>
          <FormItem name="phone" label="Phone" required="true">
            <CustomInput
              mask="+7 (999) 999-99-99"
              name="phone"
              onChange={e => {
                const value = e.target.value || "";
                const changedValue = value
                  .replace(/\)/g, "")
                  .replace(/\(/g, "")
                  .replace(/-/g, "")
                  .replace(/ /g, "");
                console.log({ value });
                console.log({ changedValue });
                setFieldValue("phone", value);
              }}
            />
          </FormItem>
          <SubmitButton type="primary" disabled={isSubmitting}>
            Submit
          </SubmitButton>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)}</pre>
        </Form>
      );
    }}
  </Formik>
);
```

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you parsing the value but you don't update it anywhere, so `changedValue` dies at the end of the scope.

Move the parsing to `onSubmit` callback, not only you making unnecessary parsing on every render but also you won't be needed another state for the parsing value.

Hint: use a single `regex` expression, no need so many replaces.

```js
const CloseForm = () => (
  <Formik
    initialValues={{ phone: '' }}
    onSubmit={(value, { setSubmitting }) => {
      const changedValue = value.phone
        .replace(/\)/g, '')
        .replace(/\(/g, '')
        .replace(/-/g, '')
        .replace(/ /g, '');

      setTimeout(() => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(changedValue, null, 2));
        setSubmitting(false);
      }, 400);
    }}
    validate={handleValidate}
  >
    {({ isSubmitting, values, setFieldValue }) => {
      return (
        <Form>
          <FormItem name="phone" label="Phone" required="true">
            <CustomInput
              mask="+7 (999) 999-99-99"
              name="phone"
              onChange={e => {
                const value = e.target.value || '';
                console.log({ value });
                setFieldValue('phone', value);
              }}
            />
          </FormItem>
          <SubmitButton type="primary" disabled={isSubmitting}>
            Submit
          </SubmitButton>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)}</pre>
        </Form>
      );
    }}
  </Formik>
);
```

[image: Edit Q-57191028-FormikSubmit]

Comment: Thank you very much! I replaced `regex` expression with `const changedValue = value.phone.replace(/\(|\)|\s|\-/g, "");`. But I have a question, how can I do this with multiple inputs, where `phone` is just one of the values? How could `onSubmit` look like in this case?

Comment: This question out of scope, I suggest asking another one

Comment: Originally I had `alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));`, which was supposed to pass all values. And in your answer it is `alert(JSON.stringify(changedValue, null, 2));`, which passes only one changed value. That' s why I'm asking.

Comment: values is an object... so use its values as you like, in the answer its values.phone, in your case pass values.somethingElse and so on

Comment: Does you answer update `values.phone` inside `values`? As I understand, `values` stay untouched, and I can get only a new variable `changedValue` additionally. My intention was to change `values.phone` inside `values` with something like `setFieldValue`.

Comment: On submit all values in the form collected to values object, from there use it whatever you like.

Comment: You have a sandbox there try playing with it, also as I said this is out of the scope, try avoiding “updating the question” after an answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but it doesn't fully answer my question. I forked your sandbox and added `setFieldValue("phone", changedValue);` to `setTimeout()`, but I get an error `Invariant Violation. Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.` If I don't get any other answers, I will post a new question on SO.

Comment: Of course you getting an error, you making infinite recursion... As I said you asking *another* question "But I have a question, how can I do this with multiple inputs, where phone is just one of the values?" which is not the original question.